# Failing to run on android

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making this game and thought I should try building it on android. but when I did and then pressed the button on my start page(the start page worked fine, and the button disappeared like it should) then nothing happened. when run in the editor it has no problem.

the script that doesn't work instantiates my prefabs from a png image which it turns into a byte array which is then used to make a list.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LevelGenerate : MonoBehaviour {
    public int[] Levels;
    public byte[] mapByte;
    public List<int> MapData;   
    public int Num;
    public Texture2D  map;
    public GameObject ParentObject;
    public GameObject obj;

    public GameObject[] prefabs; 
    public Texture2D[]  maps;
    public float Spacing;
    public int LevelNR;
    public GameObject wonCanvas;
    public GameObject lostCanvas;

    public void Restart(){
        foreach (Transform childTransform in ParentObject.transform) Destroy(childTransform.gameObject);
        createLevel(LevelNR);
        wonCanvas.SetActive(false);
        lostCanvas.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void Next(){
        foreach (Transform childTransform in ParentObject.transform) Destroy(childTransform.gameObject);
        LevelNR++;
        createLevel(LevelNR);
        wonCanvas.SetActive(false);
        lostCanvas.SetActive(false);

    }
    public void dead(){
        lostCanvas.SetActive(true);
    }
    public void won(){
        wonCanvas.SetActive(true);
    }
    public void createLevel(int levelNumber){
        LevelNR=levelNumber;

        map=maps[levelNumber];
        mapByte=map.GetRawTextureData();


        Debug.Log(mapByte.Length/3);
        for(int i=0;i<=mapByte.Length-3;i+=3){
            if(mapByte[i]==255){
                MapData.Add(0);
            }else if(mapByte[i]==205){
                MapData.Add(1);
            }else if(mapByte[i]==155){
                MapData.Add(4);
            }else if(mapByte[i]==105){
                MapData.Add(3);
            }else if(mapByte[i]==55){
                MapData.Add(5);
            }else if(mapByte[i]==0){
                MapData.Add(2);
            }else{
                MapData.Add(0);
            }

        }
        Levels=MapData.ToArray();

        for(int i=0;i<map.height;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<map.width;j++){   
                Debug.Log(Num); 

                if(Levels[Num]!=0)  
                obj=Instantiate(prefabs[Levels[Num]], new Vector3(i *Spacing, 0, j*Spacing), Quaternion.identity);
                obj.transform.SetParent(ParentObject.transform);
                Num++;
            }   
        }   
    }   
}
```

is there any of my code that is not supported on android or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: i have isolated the problem to the last for loop

Comment: i figured it out, the sprites had to be read/write enabled